# How Should I Send HTML/CSS Content To A Server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, editing

### The Situation

I have to create a web-application that allows me to, starting from a blank page, insert new `html`, images and so on, and allows to edit it with features like: `resize`, `positioning` and so on.

To figure out what I'm talking about, see: https://www.scrollkit.com in its `editor` section.

### My Question

**How should I save the new `html` I create, with the `CSS` bound to it, to my server?**

Should I use a `JSON` structure in which I put all my `elements` with something like:

```
 { 
   attributes: "",
   tag: "div",
   html: "some-html", 
   ..
 }
```

Or should I save the entire (maybe "compiled"?) `html` page to the file-system?

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: you have the right idea with json, id go the next step and use an mvc language. AngularJS is my favorite. That way, the page state is stored in JS, not DOM and is preserved for page life. To go further, you could save elements in HTML 5 localstorage. Then Page state can be preserved beyond page life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see this as an architecture question more then a code question, especially since the asker didn't specify what server side technology they are using or are comfortable with.

Here is how I would design this:

I'd have a div where all the content would go inside.  I'd optionally have a style element (with an id) that all my custom css would be written into.  I'd simply save the contents of the div and css style to the server, using ajax, when various things happened (user hit save button, perhaps auto-save every so many minutes, etc), and reload it when needed (on page load, reset button, maybe undo, etc.).

Hopefully, I'd be able to build all my insert/resize/position code to work just off of html.  If I needed to, I'd put data- elements on my html to store information I needed to make all my manipulation work.  I'd strongly hesitate to have a duplicate JavaScript structure in memory for all my elements, because it seems that nightmares could happen if they get out of sync.  However, if you have to do so, I'd also save that to the server and reload it.  I'd find a way to rebuild either the structure or the data- attributes if they don't exist.

That's a good enough start, I think.  Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: What you mean with : "I'd be able to build all my insert/resize/position code to work just off of html." it seems interesting

Comment: By "I'd be able to build all my insert/resize/position code to work just off of html.", I mean that I wouldn't have a separate array of elements stored in memory.  I'd just the DOM as the storage.  I probably would make each element movable and resizable using one of the libraries out there that does that (jQuery UI, for one), and when they wanted to add new html, I'd insert it into my div, and perhaps use one of the inline html editors to let them insert text and/or images.  Perhaps I'd have the css properties in a sidebar on the left and let them edit those as well.

Answer (score 2):

Creating an HTML editor is a very complicated task. I would use [one of existing controls](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce) that is actively maintained. But if you insist, you can use JSON and post the HTML and CSS data to an endpoint, then save it to a file or database. I don't believe keeping a node by node structure is necessary.

So, you could try the following:
*(I assume, you're using an `<iframe/>` for this HTML editor)*

```js
var data,
    // since we're editing within an iframe, 
    // we'll get the iframe document to access HTML data
    iframe = document.getElementById('editor-iframe'),
    editorDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

// gathering post data from the edited document
data = {
    // get the full html from the editor document
    html: $(editorDoc).find('html').get(0).outerHTML,
    // since the user is editing a file on the fly, you can 
    // have a <style> element within the head and modify it when 
    // user edits the file. So we can get the style contents
    // and store it separately here. 
    css: $(editorDoc).find('head style').html(),
    // add some extra metadata here
    metadata: {
        user: 'onur'
    }
};

// finally, posting the data to the endpoint when the 
// user clicks a "save" button. And you should also auto-save
// periodically to prevent data loss.
$.post('/saveFile', data);
```

Here is [**a demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/bbdTW/).

Comment: Don't just downvote, enlighten us!.. unrelated answer? code not working? what?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using XML+XHTML. Browsers can render XHTML just as well as HTML, but unlike with HTML, XML processing rules allows namespaces so the browser will just ignore unrecognized elements and attributes as long as you put them in a separate namespace. Your editor can use namespaced elements and attributes to store editor metadata that wouldn't be in the compiled HTML.

Comment: So I have to save the file every time I edit the page?

Comment: @steo: just edit your XHTML tree directly within the browser, and when you want to save the document, serialize the XHTML tree with all its metadata and send it off to the server. When you need to compile the XHTML+Editor XML to plain XHTML/HTML, all you need to do is strip all elements/attributes that are in your editor namespace.

Answer (score 0):

When I implementing something like this I saved the raw html as XML then I parsed the page accordingly.

To be more clear I used various xml blocks for different items eg:

```
<xml>
  <html>

  </html>
  <css>
  </css>
</xml>
```

Just build the structure you need. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it to keep things simple:

```
{   
    filelist: [
        {
            filename: "style.css",
            contents: ""
        },
        {
            filename: "index.js",
            contents: ""
        },
        {
            filename: "index.html",
            contents: ""
        }
    ]
}
```

If it's pure HTML, I would just keep it as one string when passing to the server and use an iframe on the client side to preview it. This would make loading simple and you can just manipulate the HTML using the DOM when sent to the client. Is there a particular reason you would need the HTML tags in any other format? I suppose if you wanted to implement some kind of content management system with re-usable blocks, you would want to change things up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Steo, when you are developing an application which has a feature to insert HTML, make sure you have a good control to avoid persistent/non-persistent XSS attacks.

If the HTML/CSS depended features are manageable, I would recommend you to go with JSON storage with proper server side validation, which may help you to keep your model clean and no technology dependent. So that you can parse the JSON and develop your application for mobile, tablet etc., later.

Having an array of JSON objects(CONFIG) copy will also help the application with undo or redo operations, which will be an important feature when working with editor.

Good luck! :-)

Answer (score -1):

With html5 i think it's simple http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp